# How to preview updated data without reload/refresh page if new data add or edit old data in next js and mongo db project

Tags: next.js, next.js13

In project I used Mongodb and next js. Here if I edited or added data in the collection of mongo db the data added to the collection but in the client side not preview automatically. When I reloaded/refreshed the client side page then the added or edited data previewed on the client side page.

## **This is my api/topics/route.js file **

```js
import { NextResponse } from "next/server";
import Topic from "@/models/topic";
import connectMongoDB from "@/dbConfig/dbConfig";

export async function POST(request) {
  try {
    await connectMongoDB();
    
    const { title, description } = await request.json();

    // Create a new topic with isPublish and isUnpublish set to false
    const newTopic = new Topic({
      title,
      description,
      isPublish: false,
      isUnpublish: false,
    });

    await newTopic.save();

    return NextResponse.json({ message: "Topic Created" }, { status: 201 });
  } catch (error) {
    return NextResponse.json({ error: error.message }, { status: 400 });
  }
}

export async function GET() {
  try {
    await connectMongoDB();

    // Fetch all topics
    const topics = await Topic.find();

    return NextResponse.json({ topics });
  } catch (error) {
    return NextResponse.json({ error: error.message }, { status: 500 });
  }
}
export async function PUT(request, { params }) {
  const { id } = params;
  const { newTitle: title, newDescription: description, isPublish:pub } = await request.json();
  await connectMongoDB();
  await Topic.findByIdAndUpdate(id, { title, description, isPublish:pub });
  return NextResponse.json({ message: "Topic updated" }, { status: 200 });
}


export async function DELETE(request) {
  const id = request.nextUrl.searchParams.get("id");
  await connectMongoDB();
  await Topic.findByIdAndDelete(id);
  return NextResponse.json({ message: "Topic deleted" }, { status: 200 });
}
```

**This is my code by which I want to preview my data in client side.**

```js
"use client"
import Link from "next/link";
import RemoveBtn from "../removeButton/RemoveBtn";
import { HiPencilAlt } from "react-icons/hi";
import { useEffect, useState } from "react";

const TopicsList = () => {
  const [topics, setTopics] = useState([]);

  const fetchTopics = async () => {
    try {
      const res = await fetch("http://localhost:3000/api/topics", {
        cache: "no-store",
      });
      if (!res.ok) {
        throw new Error("Failed to fetch topics");
      }
      const data = await res.json();
      setTopics(data.topics);
    } catch (error) {
      
      console.log("Error loading topics: ", error);
    }
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    fetchTopics();
  }, []); // Fetch topics when the component mounts

  return (
    <div className="flex items-center justify-center">
    <div className="container w-3/4">
      {topics.map((t) => (
        <div
          key={t._id}
          className="bg-emerald-50 items-start p-4 m-2 border border-slate-500 flex justify-between gap-5 rounded-md"
        >
          <div>
            <h2 className="font-bold text-2xl">{t.title}</h2>
            <div>{t.description}</div>
          </div>
  
          <div className="flex gap-2">
            <RemoveBtn id={t._id} />
            <Link href={`/editTopic/${t._id}`}>
              <HiPencilAlt size={24} />
            </Link>
          </div>
        </div>
      ))}
    </div>
  </div>
  
  );
};

export default TopicsList;
```

## I want to preview the data on client side if I add or edit the data without reload or refresh the page.

Comment: You can refere https://nextjs.org/docs/app/building-your-application/data-fetching/fetching-caching-and-revalidating